# How to set custom header for PouchDB ajax requests?

Tags: http-headers, authorization, pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB 3.2.1.
I'm trying to set `Authorization` header for all ajax requests:

```js
db.local = new $window.PouchDB(POUCHDB_NAME);

db.remote = new $window.PouchDB(COUCHDB_URI, {
    skipSetup: true,
    ajax: {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + $window.btoa('admin:admin')
        }
    }
});

// Replication
db.local.sync(db.remote, {
    live : true,
    retry: true
});
```

**But it doesn't works. See the screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot from Chrome dev tools]

Comment: did you solved this?

Comment: @DilankaRathnayake unfortunately I could not solve this problem :(

Answer (score 1):

In the latest PouchDB this is the preferred way [(click here for the docu)](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_database):

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://example.com/dbname', {
  fetch: function (url, opts) {
    opts.headers.set('Authorization', 'token-here');
    opts.headers.set('X-Some-Special-Header', 'foo');
    return PouchDB.fetch(url, opts);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think as described [here](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication#everybody-has-to-be-logged-in-to-do-anything), you also need to set:

```
{skipSetup: true}
```

In your constructor options.

Comment: Same here. I've updated my question using `skipSetup` for clarity

Comment: Do you have a live example to reproduce?

Comment: It will be hard to do, but I'll try to provide live example

Comment: I have sent you an email with exampe url